# Auto install with preseed

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, lvm, preseed

Good, I am creating a preseed for my server but I do not understand that represent the following numbers: `1024 30 1024 raid`or  `2048 60 2048 swap`                   for example.

I have two hard disks that exert raid 1: cciss / c0d0 and cciss / c0d1. Subsequently there is a group of volumes called "group-lvm", which has logical volumes. I mean, something like that:

> SCSI.CCISS (-,0,0) (cciss/c0d0) - 73.4 GB Compaq Smart Array
>
> #1 Primary 73.4 GB  k lvm
>
> SCSI.CCISS (-,0,1) (cciss/c0d1) - 73.4 GB Compaq Smart Array
>
> #1 Primary 73.4 GB  k lvm
>
> LVM VG group-lvm, LV home - 2.0 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
>
> #1     2.0 GB      f      ext4          /home
>
> LVM VG group-lvm, LV root - 10.0 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
>
> #1     10.0 GB      f      ext4          /
>
> LVM VG group-lvm, LV srv - 2.0 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
>
> #1     2.0 GB      f      ext4          /srv
>
> LVM VG group-lvm, LV swap - 4.0 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
>
> #1     4.0 GB      f      ext4          exchange
>
> LVM VG group-lvm, LV tmp - 4.0 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
>
> #1     4.0 GB      f      ext4          /tmp
>
> LVM VG group-lvm, LV var - 15.0 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
>
> #1     15.0 GB      f      ext4          /var

Answer (score 0):

The numbers represent `<minimal size>`, `<priority>` and `<maximal size>` in this order.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/xobs/debian-installer/blob/master/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt).